# Is there an easy way to emulate Dir::glob?

Tags: ruby

I have a list of filenames and I want to implement [Dir::glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) on that.

I thought that was easy because there is [File::fnmatch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) which looks like the right tool for that. However, both methods behave different in some cases:

```
# Given a directory layout like this:
# +
# |-- file
# |-+ folder
# | |-- file

# gives ['file','folder/file']
Dir.glob('**/file') 

# gives ['folder/file']
['file','folder','folder/file'].select{|n| File.fnmatch?('**/file', n) }
```

Prepending a slash solves this, but introduces another problem:

```
# gives ['file,'folder/file']
['file','folder','folder/file'].select{|n| File.fnmatch?('**/file','/'+n) }
# gives an empty array, but should give 'file' and 'folder' like Dir.glob does.
['file','folder','folder/file'].select{|n| File.fnmatch?('f*','/'+n) }
```

Has somebody solved this problem already or do I have to do some Regexp Magic (tm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try passing the `File::FNM_PATHNAME` flag,

```
 ['file','folder','folder/file'].select{|n| File.fnmatch?('**/file', n,File::FNM_PATHNAME) }
 => ["file", "folder/file"]
```

Which appears to give what you want..

Answer (score 3):

You need point a `FNM_PATHNAME` flag

```
> ['file','folder','folder/file'].select{|n| File.fnmatch?('**/file', n, File::FNM_PATHNAME) }
 => ["file", "folder/file"] 
> ['file','folder','folder/file'].select{|n| File.fnmatch?('f*',n, File::FNM_PATHNAME) }
 => ["file", "folder"]
```

Comment: Hi, I wish I could split the 'correct answer'. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this works for all cases, but **file (without slash) seems to match both your test cases:

```
 ['file', 'folder', 'folder/file'].select {|n| File.fnmatch?('**file', n) }
```